# The remainder of $1^1+2^2+3^3+\dots+98^{98}$ mod $4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

How can I solve this problem:

> If the sum $S=(1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^5+6^6...+98^{98})$ is divided by $4$ then what is the remainder?

I know that all the even terms I can ignore since $(2n)^{2n}=4^nn^{2n})$ which is divisible by $4$,but i dont know what to do next it. Also I know we can write each of them as $(99-98)^1+(99-97)^2+(99-96)^3...+(99-1)^{98}$.

Comment: For an odd $k$, what is the remainder of $k^k$ modulo $4$?

Comment: Interesting 98/2=49=1 mod 4, but it is marginally faster (by a second or so) to key it into Mathematica and look at the last 3 digits of the huge result! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S=1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^5+6^6+7^7+...97^{97}+98^{98}\equiv \\S\equiv1^1+0+3^3+0+5^5+0+7^7+...+97^{97}+0\\\equiv1^1+3^3+5^5+7^7+...+97^{97}\\\equiv1^1+0+3^3+0+5^5+0+7^7+...+97^{97}+0\\\equiv1^1+3^3+5^5+7^7+...+97^{97}\equiv\\S\equiv1+(4k-1)^3+(4k+1)^5+(4k-1)^7+(4k+1)^9+(4k-1)^{11}...+(4k+1)^{97}\\\equiv1+(-1)^3+1^5+(-1)^7+...+(-1)^{97}\\(1,3,5,..97)=49 ,term\\so\\\equiv1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+....=1
$$

Comment: How many odd numbers in 1,...,98?

Comment: $$1-3-5-7-...-97\\number -of-term=\frac{last(term)-first(term)}{step}+1\\so\\step=3-1=5-3=2\\\frac{97-1}{2}+1=48+1$$

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. But Daniel Fischer made the key observation as a comment to the question 16 mins before your answer, so putting up an answer that is obvious from the comment, but wrong, is not particularly helpful, especially when it remains uncorrected for half an hour.

Comment: sorry , but I am poor in typing latex , it takes too long (by me)

Comment: Ok, I relent! +1

Answer (score 4):

In mod $4$, note that for any positive integer $m$,
$$(2m)^{2m}=(4m^2)^m\equiv 0$$$$(4m-1)^{4m-1}\equiv (-1)^{4m-1}\equiv -1$$$$(4m-3)^{4m-3}\equiv 1^{4m-3}\equiv 1$$
and that $97=4\cdot 25-3,\ 95=4\cdot 24-1$.

Hence, we have
$$S\equiv 24\cdot (-1)+25\cdot 1\equiv 1.$$