# $P=1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^5+\ldots \ldots \ldots+48^{48}+49^{49}+50^{50}$. What is the remainder when $P$ is divided by 8?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $P=1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^5+\ldots \ldots \ldots+48^{48}+49^{49}+50^{50}$. What is the remainder when $P$ is divided by 8 ?

A. 1

B. 3

C. 5

D. 6

E. 7

Is modular arithmetic, chinese remainder, or Fermat the solution?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Modular arithmetic. You can ignore all but one even number.

Comment: Please include your efforts. We are NOT a Homework Answering Service!

Comment: @Mike this seems like a competition problem.

Comment: In this case I'd say brute force is the best bet.  It's pretty trivial to figure out what $even^{even}\pmod 8$ is and using Fermat it's pretty easy to figure out what $odd^{odd}\pmod 8$ is.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923752/the-remainder-of-112233-dots9898-mod-4 also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325529/find-x-such-that-sum-k-12014-kk-equiv-x-pmod-10 and probably many more.

Comment: $(2k+1)^2=8n+1$

Comment: Have you looked at those links, Trans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $n^n\equiv0 \pmod{8}$ for all even $n\geq 4$.
Fermat gives $n^4\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ for odd $n$, so
\begin{align*}
n^n\equiv n\pmod{8} \quad\text{if $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$} \\
n^n\equiv n^3\pmod{8} \quad\text{if $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
P &\equiv 2^2+\sum_{k=0}^{12} (4k+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{11} (4k+3)^3\\
&\equiv 4+(7\cdot 1+6\cdot 5)+(6\cdot 3+6\cdot (-1))\\
&\equiv 53 \equiv5\pmod{8}.
\end{align*}